# Python App working on local host, but not on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have developed a simple inventory app and it is working well on local host, but it is only partially working on Heroku. It does not show any error, but it is shows only a static page and does not show any dynamically created contents.
What could be the reason behind this problem?
Here are the snapshots to make the difference clear:
[image: Local host]

[image: Deployed on Heroku]

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production setup. So I guess you have to configure Heroku to do that.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough detail here for anyone to begin to answer this.

Comment: please provide more details, otherwise things to check: do you get an error in your browser console? Do you get any errors in your heroku console? have you migrated your DB? have you configured your staticfiles correctly according to heroku's guides? If you do not provide any details, nobody will be able to help you

Comment: I have made migrations before deploying. Maybe the problem is related to static files configuration.

Comment: Have you actually entered those items into the database on Heroku?

Comment: Actually I don't understand Django. I am trying to learn. I followed a video tutorial and it worked well on my machine. After finishing the project, I deployed it to Heroku and it didn't work the same.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Your comment helped me solve the problem. I created a super user and added the items and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has docs about settings for [static path](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#static-assets-and-file-serving)

so you need static dir, then you need to run [shell command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#one-off-dynos)

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```